# BASH: Assigning find output to value includes options

Tags: bash, find

I want to get all files with a specific extention and assign them to a variable. However, when I print the variable, the output includes the options of the find command:

```
annotations=$(find -type f -name "*.fna")
echo "${annotations[@]}"
```

```
./dir1/file1.fna
./dir2/file2.fna
...
./dir10/file10.fna -type f -name *.fna
```

The output above includes all the files I need, but I have no idea why the options are included in the array. When I loop for each of the files in the variable above, I get the same output:

```
for fullfile in "${annotations[@]}"
do
echo "$fullfile"
done
```

```
./dir1/file1.fna
./dir2/file2.fna
...
./dir10/file10.fna 
-type 
f 
-name 
*.fna
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as unreproducible. I'm sure you are seeing the results you tell us, but the code in your question does not reproduce those symptoms.

Comment: Or TS has a file './dir10/file10.fna -type f -name *.fna'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `-exec basename` to be included in your `find` command to capture only the files:

```
annotations=$(find -type f -name "*.fna" -exec basename "{}" \;)
echo "${annotations[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you, that gave me the corect output! IThough I'm not sure why the options were included in the variable in teh first place, is it a peculiarity of the $() command?

Comment: No, it's not about `$()`, it's the default feature of `find` command to output the files with complete path, try running: `find -type f -name "*.fna"`, you'll get it!

Answer (score 0):

Strange indeed, I've checked your commands in my shell and results are fine.
Maybe except this second one with for loop, you miss closed quote in first line.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 annotations=$(find -type f -name "*.fna")
 for fullfile in "${annotations[@]}"
 do
   echo "$fullfile"
 done
```

Output:

```
./test.fna
./test/test.fna
```

Comment: Haha, I doublechecked that a lot to make sure I hadn't gone mad. The other answer solved the issue, thank you nonetheless.